# How can I create a link to a custom form in Outlook 2003

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2003, outlook-form

If I created a custom form (including Script) in Outlook 2003, published it to the personal forms library, the only way I know to create a item out of this form is "File -> New -> Choose Form... -> Personal Forms Library -> Select my Form -> Ok".

Is there a faster way? For example, a link from the desktop or from the Outlook favorites folder?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one of [the first 2 answers to this SU question](https://superuser.com/questions/97421/how-to-reply-with-an-outlook-template-in-outlook-2003) will help you.

:)

Comment: No, unfortunately this works only with forms without script. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This VBA code will display the form. You can call it from a button.

Replace FormName with your form name.

```
Sub DisplayFormName()

    Dim MyFolder
    Dim myItem As MailItem

    ' create new outgoing message based on a form
    Set MyFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set myItem = MyFolder.items.Add("IPM.Note.FormName")
    myItem.Display

End Sub
```

Editor and button help - http://www.slipstick.com/developer/how-to-use-outlooks-vba-editor/

Macro security should be set to medium.

Button help - http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/macrobutton.htm